# Raw fish on Shabbos

Tags: muktzeh, fish

Is raw fish considered muktza?

Comment: See also http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/4036

Comment: More details would make your question better. For example there is a difference between sushi, sashimi, and a whole fish which hasn't been prepared to consume.

Answer (score 4):

Aruch HaShulchan OH 308:57 quotes the Rambam that (raw) unsalted fish cannot be touched.

סימן שח סעיף נז
עוד כתב שם: "מטלטלין בשר תפוח, והיינו מסריח, מפני שהוא מאכל לחיה. ומטלטלין בשר חי בין תפל בין מליח מפני שראוי לאדם, וכן דג מליח. אבל התפל - אסור לטלטלו" עכ"ל.
ואצלינו שאין חיות מצויות - אסור לטלטל בשר תפוח, אבל הטור והש"ע סעיף ל"א כתבו: מפני שראוי לכלבים, וכלבים מצוים בכל מקום ומותר לטלטלו, והרמב"ם נקיט לשון הגמרא (קכ"ח:) ע"ש. ועל הטור וש"ע יש לומר שבזמן הגמרא היו חיות מצויות, לפיכך אומר: מפני שהוא מאכל לחיה, ובזמן הטור וש"ע לא היו מצויות, לפיכך כתבו לכלבים (ק"נ שם), אבל לא כן משמע לשון הגמרא ע"ש. ואמנם בתוספות שם פירשו דתפוח אינו מסריח אלא הוא בשר תפל, וכן הוא בפירוש רש"י שברי"ף ע"ש וצ"ע (ועיין דרישה).

Comment: consult your local Orthodox rabbi, though. This Aruch Hashulchan was written before **sushi** became popular. It could be that nowadays, this new *metzius* would cause a corresponding halachic change. Just as the Aruch Hashulchan was speaking of changed metzius from the times of the gemara.

Comment: Josh thats what intrigues me about this particular question I want to know if any Modern responsa  or Rav or Shiur addresses it?

Comment: not that i know of...

Comment: It did not address the muktza issue, but there was an article in the Journal of Halacha & Contemporary Society on the preparation of sushi on shabbat.  The article concludes that producing a well constructed maki roll constitutes boneh, and is therefore prohibited.  I cannot disagree more.

Comment: Even if shusi became popular isnt the halacha the same always if it was a gezaira and even if the metzias changes?

Comment: @sam, muktza is based on a mental state.  If I think, "well, I'm not going to use this" it becomes muktza.  If in the past there was no use for raw fish, it was by default muktza.  If I had a freshly caught salmon nowadays, and the skills and inclination to make sushi from it, it seemingly would not be muktza.

Comment: I think something is not muktzah if it has a permitted use to it; now that sushi is popular, raw fish has a permitted use, namely eating.

Comment: I think you probably meant 'cannot be moved'. Muktzah may be touched.

Answer (score 3):

The Shulhan Aruch writes that raw meat isn't muktze because people are it that way. Rav Yitshak Yosef writes that it depends what the minhag haolam is for eating meat. If people eat it raw nowadays, than it's not mukse - if not, than it is.  I would imagine the same applies to fish.

Answer (score 3):

This piece is from the [OUKosher website](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/is-it-permissible-to-make-sushi-on-shabbos-is-it-muktza/):

Is it permissible to make Sushi on Shabbos? Is it muktza?

Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 308:32) writes that unsalted raw fish is muktza, because it serves no purpose on Shabbos.

> However in our days, if one has cuts of raw fish that are edible as
>   sushi, then they are not muktza. However, Rav Belsky, zt”l, questioned
>   whether one may make sushi on Shabbos.

The Chayei Adam 39:1 writes that the melacha of boneh (building) applies to food as well, and that attaching foods together to produce a desired picture or shape, is included in this prohibition. Since shaping sushi might be included in this prohibition, Rav Belsky, zt”l, recommended that one should not make sushi on Shabbos with the intent of making a specific design or pattern.