# Is sushi Muktzeh?

Tags: shabbat, food, muktzeh, fish

According to Bab. Shab. 128a, unsalted fish is Muktzeh (because it's inedible, presumably).

So is sushi Muktzeh? Does it make a difference whether the sushi is totally prepared (rolled or plated or whatever - I don't do sushi so my understanding of it may be off) or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Raw fish on Shabbos](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5824/raw-fish-on-shabbos)

Comment: I'm not asking about Stam raw fish. According to the Gemara it is Muktzeh. I'm asking about something that is considered food that is, essentially, no different, except by social convention.

Comment: @SethJ Isn't all raw fish food then? I don't really do sushi, but would a sushi eater go to order a fresh piece of raw fish from the fish counter at the grocery and eat it? Or at least, find it somewhat enjoyable, though a little bland? Or is sushi fist special somehow?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I love how you said "I don't really do sushi," because that's how I generally express my relationship to sushi. I definitely don't do sushi. I cannot fathom the desire to eat the stuff.  I've tried and tried and tried, and the best I can do is tolerate it. Having said that, however, people love it. In any case, you've sort of paraphrased my question. "Is sushi fish special somehow?"

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, a sushi (or rather [sashimi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sashimi)) eater would go to order a fresh piece of raw fish from the (sushi) fish counter at the grocery and eat it. It isn't bland ;-)

Comment: My understanding of sushi, from having asked some of those making it (inevitably, they're all Japanese. I have yet to see a Hassid with a beard making the sushi rolls!) said that raw fish must be processed in a certain way or frozen first to kill the bacteria. You can't just catch a salmon, fillet it and eat it without seriously risking your health. So, in a sense, raw fish is not exactly sashimi. (I'm still waiting to ask a Japanese mashgiach.)

Comment: Technically, schmaltz and matjas herring are also raw fish, but they're not called sashimi. People have been eating this at Shabbat Kiddush for over a century, if not longer!

Comment: @DanF Not only have I not seen a Chassid making sushi rolls, I’ve even heard of some claiming it’s Chukas HaGoyim to eat sushi. As if Gefilte fish, originally a (non-Jewish) Polish delicacy, is any better.

Comment: Sushi is edible

Answer (score 10):

I have heard that Rabbi Avraham Yosef Shlita has said in a Shiur that it is not Muktze, since this is the way people eat it.